# How Can I use speech recognition in electron js

Tags: javascript, electron, speech-recognition

I want to use speech recognition in my electron.js app but it seems that Speech Recognition with electron is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

you can use electron speech package
reference :https://github.com/noffle/electron-speech

Comment: I tried using electron-speech I got `err network` message then it fired a error showing `Uncaught Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ('network')` Not sure why is that so

Comment: try with restarting a node server

Comment: I tried but it shows always the same problem

Comment: check this and try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835083/webkitspeechrecognition-throws-error-network

Comment: how do I config the API key because I don't know because I am not using it.

Comment: refer this bro  https://github.com/noffle/electron-speech/issues/5    they said google shut downed the chrome speech api in electron